# Where is FragmentHostCallback created in Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

When I checked `lifecycle` of `fragment` I found something that I do not understand.

#### FragmentHostCalback

> Fragments may be hosted by any `object`; such as an `Activity`. In order to host fragments, implement `FragmentHostCallback`, overriding the methods applicable to the host.

#### Question

- Where created `FragmentHostCallback` in `Fragment`?

I think `FragmentHostCallback` created at `onInflate` or `onAttach`. However, I couldn't find any code related to creating `FragmentHostCallback` there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fragments themselves don't host Fragments - as mentioned, it is an Activity or equivalent object that creates a `FragmentHostCallback` object. For example, `FragmentActivity` contains its own implementation of `FragmentHostCallback` called [HostCallbacks](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/fragment/src/main/java/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentActivity.java#849).

You never interact with this object directly, rather, the `FragmentHostCallback` is passed to the [`FragmentController.createController()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentController.html#createController(androidx.fragment.app.FragmentHostCallback%3C?%3E)), which is what `FragmentActivity`, in this case, uses to trigger lifecycle changes and other signals from the Activity to the `FragmentManager` that you actually interact with.